# Is checking if a variable is defined to be avoided in Python?

Tags: python, optional-parameters

I often read that checking if a variable is defined is somehow a bad design choice. But I see no other way to handle optional parameters in class methods. So is something wrong with the way the optional parameter of `make_sound_twice` is handled in the following code?

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.default_sound = 'meow'

    def make_sound_twice(self, sound=None):
        if sound is None:
            sound = self.default_sound
        print("{sound} {sound}".format(sound=sound))


kitty = Cat()

kitty.make_sound_twice()

custom_sound = 'hiss'
kitty.make_sound_twice(custom_sound)

custom_sound = 0
kitty.make_sound_twice(custom_sound)
```

This prints the following lines:

```
meow meow
hiss hiss
0 0
```

`self` is not defined at that point, so I can not simply set a default value instead of `None`:

```
def make_sound_twice(self, sound=self.default_sound):
```

Comment: Your code isn't checking if the variable is defined, it's checking its value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code you show.**  In fact, it's pretty idiomatic.

> I often read that checking if a variable is defined is somehow a bad design choice

In the example you show, the variable *is* defined.  It's just set to `None`.

Checking it with `is None` is completely fine.  In some circumstances, the following technique could be used to replace all falsy values (`None`, `0`, `""` etc) with a default:

```
DEFAULT = ...

def f(arg = None):
   arg = arg or DEFAULT
   ...
```

However, this is not applicable to your case since you state that you need to be able to pass zero to your function.

Comment: Usage of the `or` operator in this case should be avoided **if** there's a legitimate reason to pass a 'falsy' value as an argument. In this case, it will print the `default_sound` if the passed `sound` argument is for example `""` or `0`. Actually OP states that it's one of his requirements to be able to print `0`.

Comment: @ruohola: I was just adding a note to my answer to this effect.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @ruohola: Actually, I completely overlooked the zero in the question (thanks for pointing that out).  Let me edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I always use `is None`, so I don't shoot myself in the foot when 0 is a valid input. Kitty saying "meow meow" where I expected "0 0" just happened to me in real life, and confused me longer than it should have. Though the cat is still a metaphor. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it slightly cleaner:

```
def make_sound_twice(self, sound=None):
    sound = self.default_sound if sound is None else sound
    print("{sound} {sound}".format(sound=sound))
```

Or alternatively:

```
def make_sound_twice(self, sound=None):
    sound = sound if sound is not None else self.default_sound
    print("{sound} {sound}".format(sound=sound))
```

But what you're doing right now is just as idiomatic Python.